# connection php with mysql error using mamp

Tags: mysql, connection, mamp

i trying to learn php but found an issue.. im using mamp on a windows PC. and when im trying to connect my php with mysql a get this error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)..... 
in mysql i got the info username and password are 'root', host:localhost port:8889
and this is my code..

```
function connectToDb()
{
  try{
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=tutorials','root','root');
  }
  catch (PDOException $e){
    die ($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

any help will be appreciate.... thanks...

Comment: If you get it then,please update me

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will work...

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'guest';
$dbpass = 'guest123';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

// make the current db as your DB_Name

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('DB_Name', $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

add port number also to your code...

```
mysql:host=localhost:8889
```

And it will look like this

```
function connectToDb()
    {
      try{
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8889; dbname=tutorials','root','root');
      }
      catch (PDOException $e){
        die ($e->getMessage());
      }
    }
```

or your credentials will be incorrect ie, try the connection with password=' '.